# How to convert getRGB(x,y) integer pixel to Color(r,g,b,a) in Java?

Tags: java, image, colors

I have the integer pixel I got from `getRGB(x,y)`, but I don't have any clue about how to convert it to RGBA format. For example, `-16726016` should be `Color(0,200,0,255)`. Any tips?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If I'm guessing right, what you get back is an unsigned integer of the form `0xAARRGGBB`, so

```
int b = (argb)&0xFF;
int g = (argb>>8)&0xFF;
int r = (argb>>16)&0xFF;
int a = (argb>>24)&0xFF;
```

would extract the color components. However, a quick look at the [docs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int%29) says that you can just do

```
Color c = new Color(argb);
```

or

```
Color c = new Color(argb, true);
```

if you want the alpha component in the Color as well.

**UPDATE**

Red and Blue components are inverted in original answer, so the right answer will be:

```
int r = (argb>>16)&0xFF;
int g = (argb>>8)&0xFF;
int b = (argb>>0)&0xFF;
```

**updated also in the first piece of code**

Comment: @Gevorg: Might be. But that's fairly obvious to notice when testing the code. :)

Comment: @AKX Unless you test it with (0,200,0,255)! ;)

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB%28%29: Bits 24-31 are alpha, 16-23 are red, 8-15 are green, 0-7 are blue

Answer (score 28):

```
    Color c = new Color(-16726016, true);
    System.out.println(c.getRed());
    System.out.println(c.getGreen());
    System.out.println(c.getBlue());
    System.out.println(c.getAlpha());
```

prints out:

```
0
200
0
255
```

Is that what you mean?