# How can I get the RGB values of a 'TYPE_3BYTE_BGR' image?

Tags: java, image

I have an image with `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` and I want to convert it to a `TYPE_INT_RGB`.

Though I have searched, I have not found a method to do this.  I want to convert the image pixel by pixel.  However, it seems that `BufferedImage.getRGB(i, j)` doesn't work.

How can I get the RGB values in an image of type `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`?

Comment: you can do it manually as you are proposing, but it would be much simpler just to create a target BufferedImage with TYPE_INT_RGB, and just draw the source image into the destination BufferedImage.

Comment: Tried your suggestion. using "result.getGraphics().drawImage(source, 0, 0, null);". Pixels arent reverted in result image.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "getRGB(i,j) doesn't work".  getRGB returns a packed int; you need to decode it.

```
int color = image.getRGB(i,j);
int r = (argb)&0xFF;
int g = (argb>>8)&0xFF;
int b = (argb>>16)&0xFF;
int a = (argb>>24)&0xFF;
```

See [How to convert get.rgb(x,y) integer pixel to Color(r,g,b,a) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534116/how-to-convert-get-rgbx-y-integer-pixel-to-colorr-g-b-a-in-java)

Comment: I think you can safely ignore the alpha channel since TYPE_3BYTE_BGR has no alpha channel.

Comment: yes, I decode it like this, and then set 'setRGB' to draw the TYPE_INT_RGB image, but at last I get two different images.