# How to get the rgb values of a jpeg image in TYPE_3BYTE_BGR?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, jpeg, rgb

I have this image:

[image: Google image]

I'd like to extract the RGB values of this image in an `int[]`. This is what I've done so far for PNG images:

```
File f = new File("t.jpg");
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(f);
int[] ib = img.getRGB(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), null, 0, img.getWidth());
Color c = new Color(ib[0]);
System.out.println(c.getRed() + " " + c.getGreen() + " " + c.getBlue());
```

But here I get this output: `255 128 128` which is not expected since I clearly see (and have verified in several image editors) that the pixel at (0,0) has these values `255 255 255`.

I noticed that the type returned by `img.getType()` is equal to [TYPE_3BYTE_BGR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_3BYTE_BGR) so I guess it's a decoding issue happening behind the scene but I can't figure out how to workaround it (or get a clearer understanding of what's happening).

Does anyone would have a suggestion on how to decode this type properly?

Comment: Why don't you use [`getRGB(int x, int y)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int)) instead of [`getRGB(int startX, int startY, int w, int h, int[] rgbArray, int offset, int scansize)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int[],%20int,%20int))?

Comment: You could convert the image on the file to TYPE_INT_RGB by painting it into a new BufferedImage. But rough & ready, but should work

Comment: @Eng.Fouad 1. Because this method is more efficient. 2. Because it's very likely to return the same result (although I didn't test it yet)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816821/how-can-i-get-the-rgb-values-of-a-type-3byte-bgr-image?

Comment: I'm asking here a question about a specific image + a specific format (JPEG), which is different than the potential duplicate...

Comment: There's definitely something weird about this specific image.  If I open it in an image editor and save-as, the resulting new file gives the expected pixel values.  There must be some encoding difference but that's supposed to be abstracted away by `getRGB()`.  I don't know what's going on here, but it's fishy.

Comment: Your image's color model likely is not RGB but CMYK, and you'll need to get the RGB data directly into your BufferedImage's raster. Please check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408613/problem-reading-jpeg-image-using-imageio-readfile-file?rq=1) and it's answer for the likely solution to your problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I thought of that, but the [0,0] pixel value is 0xffff8080, which doesn't produce white in CMYK.  I even checked out LAB just in case but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After extensive testing of different solutions, I came out with a bug for the class `com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader` (the class used for the decoding of JPEGs by the `ImageIO` class).

If I do (recommended by Oracle as this should work with all JVM and by many other threads in SO):

```
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("t.jpg"));
```

then I get the redish image.

In the other hand, if I do:

```
JPEGImageDecoder jpegDec = JPEGCodec.createJPEGDecoder(new FileInputStream("t.jpg"));
BufferedImage bi = jpegDec.decodeAsBufferedImage();
```

then I get the image correctly decoded. (note that `com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec` is a specific class of the Sun/Oracle JVM and thus this solution is not portable).

Finally, the other approach that I tried which works is using `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage()`. The image is loaded asynchronously (small disadvantage in my opinion) but at least it could load my image properly. I'm not 100% sure that this last solution is portable on all platforms/JVMs though.