# Java - reading a compressed bitmap

Tags: java, bitmap

I'm looking to read in the RGB values of a **bitmap** (or the hex colour codes, either work).

I have tried both this code :

```
 File image = serverConfig.get(map.bmp);
BufferedImage buffer = ImageIO.read(image);
dimX = buffer.getWidth();
dimY = buffer.getHeight();
byte[] pixlesB = (byte[]) buffer.getRaster().getDataElements(0, 0, buffer.getWidth(), buffer.getHeight(), null);
```

and this code :

```
File image = serverConfig.get(map.bmp);
BufferedImage buffer = ImageIO.read(image);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(buffer, "bmp", baos );
baos.flush();
byte[] pixlesB = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
```

The both work fine for a small bitmap, but when I load a large bitmap, the data gets compressed and the array returns a bunch of semi random numbers.

for example:
A green pixel will read 2,2,2 instead of 0,255,0
A red pixel will read 5,5,5 instead of 255,0,0
A yellow pixel will read 8,8,8 instead of 255,255,0

The bitmaps I'm using only include the colours red, yellow and green.
My problem is I have no way of knowing what colour 2,2,2 relates to without checking it manually (which I cannot do since it changes with each bitmap)

I know that there is some metadata in the bitmap that specifies 2 is green, but I don't know how to access it or use it to turn 2 back into 0,255,0

And this is not a duplicate of [Java - get pixel array from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image) since that doesn't mention compressed files.
And while I did ask this question a while back, it was just redirected to the above site.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Just thought this might make the question a bit clearer. I believe the file is being read correctly, it is just compressed. How do I decompress it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the rgb values of a jpeg image in TYPE\_3BYTE\_BGR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959626/how-to-get-the-rgb-values-of-a-jpeg-image-in-type-3byte-bgr)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read an image as a bitmap or as rgb values, you need to transform the image's format first.

Jpeg is a compressed image format, you need to use a tool or library in order to read as rgb.

check this answer:
[How to get the rgb values of a jpeg image in TYPE_3BYTE_BGR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959626/how-to-get-the-rgb-values-of-a-jpeg-image-in-type-3byte-bgr)

Hope this helps