# Converting integer notation to RGB notation?

Tags: java, integer, rgb

I'm trying to convert FROM integer notation TO RGB notation.

> "Integer notation is a value from 0 to 16777215 and it can be obtained from a rgb code rgb(R,G,B) using the formula 256*256*R+256*G+B."

I understand that, but what is the formula to convert from integer notation to RGB?

So if I enter 887766, I should get back (13,139,214) - how would I go about doing that?

Cheers guys

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert get.rgb(x,y) integer pixel to Color(r,g,b,a) in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534116/how-to-convert-get-rgbx-y-integer-pixel-to-colorr-g-b-a-in-java)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [`java.awt.Color`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)

```
Color color = new Color(intValue);
System.out.println(color.getRed() + ", " + color.getGreen() + ", " + color.getBlue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as: `new Color(intValue)`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "how can I convert the integer to something a human can look at to understand the R,G,B values", you could convert to hexadecimal.  Assuming you understand hex.  For example, red is ff0000.

See `Integer.toHexString()`  You may wish to add a leading "0x" for clarity.

If you literally mean how do I get 3 rgb values as 0-255, check out the link @Jeroen provided