# Get pixel color from image in Vaadin

Tags: image, vaadin, pixel

I have an image and I want to get pixel color from image. Something like this:

```
image.getPixel(100,100).Color
```

Is it possible in **Vaadin**?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that com.vaadin.ui.Image.getSource() method will return a FileResource you can use this code

```
FileResource resource = (FileResource) image.getSource();
File file = resource.getSourceFile();
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
img.getRGB(0,0);
```

Method BufferedImage.getRGB() returns integer that represents rgba color. You can extract Red, Green, Blue and Alpha values using method provided in this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534116/how-to-convert-get-rgbx-y-integer-pixel-to-colorr-g-b-a-in-java).

Assuming other scenario ( getSource() returned ExternalResource i.e. ) I would strongly suggest writing custom Vaadin component based on GWT Image which make conversion of the link/resource/file/image to BufferedImage before displaying content to user. Therefore you will be able to actually get BufferedImage from your custom component every time you need it.