# Getting the Color value of any pixel in the given bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I'm working on android's canvas view. I just want to know if this condition is valid semantically.

`if(bitmap.getPixel(x,y) == Color.WHITE)`

I logged the value of Color.WHITE by:

`int white = Color.WHITE;` 
and this gave me the value of -1 and value of black color was -1633377 something.

I found the way of getting the value of any pixel in bitmap by **getPixel()** method and it returns an ARGB value. I've tried various ways to do this but none succeeded.
Can you guys help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your if clause should work to check, if pixel's color is white. See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

Answer (score 3):

Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534116/how-to-convert-get-rgbx-y-integer-pixel-to-colorr-g-b-a-in-java)

The color's Alpha, Red, Green and Blue components are each stored on one byte (so values in [0-255]) and those 4 bytes are packed in a java "int" which is usually 4 bytes.

You get negative values because you use a signed int, in C++ you would use a unsigned int, but those are not available in Java, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854166/declaring-an-unsigned-int-in-java)

So to answer your question, yes your condition is valid semantically, -1 is the (signed) int value for 0xFFFFFFFF, and Black is not zero probably because this is opaque black, so with alpha=255 => 0xFF000000