# What's the equivalent of Java Android.graphics.Paint setColor(int color) in Xamarin - C#?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Sample code :

```
using Android.Graphics;

int _color
Paint mPaint;

mPaint.Color = ?     // Here I'm confused.
```

In Java :

```
mPaint.setColor( _color );
```

**What will be in Xamarin.Android ?**

**How to set color in Paint from int ?**

---

Reference i made :

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setColor(int)
- https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Graphics.Paint.Color/

---

Any answers !

Comment: Not sure why you are using an `int` to store the value of a color, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534116/how-to-convert-get-rgbx-y-integer-pixel-to-colorr-g-b-a-in-java

Comment: I just want to know the Xamarin equivalent of **Android,Graphics.Paint.setColor(int color)**in Java

Comment: Sure just pull out your favourite Java decompiler and see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I got a solution for this.

> Methods which start with `get` and `set` may be mapped to properties:
>
> http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/api_design/#Properties
>
> The Paint.setColor(int) method is bound as the Paint.Color property:
>
> http://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Graphics.Paint.Color/
>
> Instead of an `int` value, it instead takes an `Android.Graphics.Color`
>   structure:
>
> ```
> mPaint.Color = new Android.Graphics.Color (_color);
> ```

---

Refer : [Bug 37716](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37716#c2)

Thanks @Jonathan_Pryor.