# Java - Understanding about image.getRGB(x,y) output in Binary term

Tags: java, image, colors, rgb

i use image.getRGB(x,y); and the result is : **-16777216**

When i convert **-16777216** to binary term, i get result :

**1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000**

My question is, what the meaning for each binary above? (can you explain where is Red, Green, Blue, Alpha **without** using Color Class)

Thanks for help.

Comment: IDK why you would want to look at a color in terms of its binary values. The integer values seem more useful, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534116/how-to-convert-get-rgbx-y-integer-pixel-to-colorr-g-b-a-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You accidentally converted to 64 bit (`long`) instead of 32 bit (`int`).

The correct binary representation is

```
1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

This value contains data for the 4 channels:

```
combined:     1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
-----------------------------------------------------
alpha:        1111 1111
blue:                   0000 0000
green:                            0000 0000
red:                                        0000 0000
```

Which means this is a fully opaque black color.

Answer (score 3):

An `int` has 32 bits, not `64`, so the bits of `-16777216` are in fact

```
1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

The first 8 bits are for alpha. The next 8 bits are for red. The next 8 bits are for green. The last 8 bits are for blue. For this colour:

```
alpha = 1111 1111 = 255
  red = 0000 0000 = 0
green = 0000 0000 = 0
 blue = 0000 0000 = 0
```

If all 3 RGB values are `0` it represents black. `255` is the maximum possible alpha value, meaning that the colour is not transparent at all.