# java - Binary AND (&) operation for image.getRGB(x,y);

Tags: java, image, binary, rgb

Look the code below:

```
image.getRGB(x,y) & 0x000000FF
```

When the result image.getRGB(x,y) is **-16777216**, the AND operation result is 0 (BLACK COLOR)

When the result image.getRGB(x,y) is **-1**, the AND operation result is 255 (WHITE COLOR)

My question is, if you look to my related article in [Java - Understanding about image.getRGB(x,y) output in Binary term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240069/java-understanding-about-image-getrgbx-y-output-in-binary-term) you can see the result of image.getRGB(x,y) in binary term include Alpha, Red, Green, and Blue (32 bit) but 0x000000FF is only 8-bit; for example:

```
image.getRGB : 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0x000000FF : 1111 1111
image.getRGB & 0x000000FF : 0000 0000
```

Second Example :

```
image.getRGB : 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
0x000000FF : 1111 1111
image.getRGB & 0x000000FF : 1111 1111
```

How they compare between 8 bit of 0x00000FF with 32 bit image.getRGB so that they get result 0 or 255 like my case above?

Comment: Are you sure you made no mistake. This code outputs: 
`System.out.println(0xFF<<24 & 0xFF); → 0`
`System.out.println(Color.black.getRGB()); → -16777216` 
`System.out.println(Color.black.getRGB() & 0xFF); → 0`

Comment: @maljam : sorry, i has been edited my question. you can check again above. thanks

Comment: `-16777216` == `0xFF00000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply think of them as numbers, and regardless of the number of bits, you should align the numbers with the bits representing the same power of 2 together and then do the binary operation:

```
im.getRGB :       1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0x000000FF :      0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
                  ^^^^ ^^^^                     ^^^^ ^^^^
im.getRGB & 0xFF: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 = 0
```

Same thing with the other example:

```
im.getRGB :       1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
0x000000FF :      0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
                  ^^^^ ^^^^ ^^^^ ^^^^ ^^^^ ^^^^ ^^^^ ^^^^
im.getRGB & 0xFF: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 = 255
```

Comment: great answer ! Thanks!