# Covert color to rgb value in java

Tags: java

I know a formula to convert a colour to its RGB.
Eg.

```
Color c=new Color(100,100,100);
Int rgb1= c.getRed()*65536+c.getGreen()*256+c.getBlue();
```

This is how we get single RGB value.

Using java programming

```
int rgb2=c.getRGB();
```

when I compare this two rgb1 and rgb2, they show a different value.
What's wrong in my first equation. Please kindly solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: What does getRead() return?

Comment: Sorry its getRed(). I have corrected it.

Comment: As a side note, a left-shift `a << b` is mathematically equivalent to a multiplication `a * 2^b`. It would be more idiomatic to do those multiplications as left-shifts since you are working with packed bytes rather than an actual number. `(red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because the first way ignores the Alpha value of the color.
You can see that `c.getAlpha()` returns 255 and you don't use this value, but `c.getRGB();` does use it, so it returns `FF646464` (in hex base), which is different from `646464`.

Comment: Did not think of that. Can you please show me how to add alpha value.

Comment: Look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534116/how-to-convert-get-rgbx-y-integer-pixel-to-colorr-g-b-a-in-java

Comment: Here's an example like the one in the OP which shows this is the case. http://ideone.com/dWwtk8

Comment: @Radiodef thanks for you answer. But i know that one. I just need a correct version of my first equation

Comment: If you mean an expression which uses multiplication, you can find that according to my other comment. `(c.getAlpha() * 16777216) + ...` http://ideone.com/CdzusM

Comment: Yes @Radiodef. You are right. Thanks a lot. That is helpfull.